# Show suggestions to user and get input

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework with C# and my requirement is to show few images one by one to user and get feedback on each of them by click of button.
Later I need to process all the inputs collected.
I have implemented this logic inside a single step dialog within a waterfall.
I was trying to implement it by calling the same dialog again until all images have been shown to user, but the problem is that either same image keeps coming again and again or only one image is shown.
I wanted to know if this approach is feasible to achieve the desired functionality or I should consider taking any other approach

Comment: I fail to understand _"the problem is that either same image keeps coming again and again or only one image is shown"_?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. What i meant is that I am trying to build a logic which can call same dialog again and again to display the image and get input from user.         
Other way can be that the next dialog calls the previous dialog until a specific condition is met.

Comment: Showing some code will be better, also I feel this requirement is not specific to BotFramework, am I correct?

Comment: I am using bot framework. Will post some code in some time

Comment: Hi Kenny, I am using bot framework and a  waterfall dialog. In the second step of waterfall, I want to show 5 images one by one with like and dislike buttons to get feedback. I was trying to use validation or to send back control from next step to same step again to achieve this.
But I believe i will have to change approach, probably is should not keep this step in waterfall. Any ideas?